# nginx HTTPS Redirect

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, https

I'm trying to get my site to use HTTPS only.  I've looked all over stackoverflow and tried many of the suggested settings for the nginx settings file for the site, but I still can't get all address combinations to work.  What do I need to change in the file to get it to work?

These two address combinations don't redirect -

- http://www.example.com > No Redirect (Errors Out)
- https://example.com > No Redirect (Errors Out)

Here's what the settings file looks like -

```
server {
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 default_server ipv6only=off;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    # rest of config file...
}
```

Comment: replace $host variable with $server_name. Should work!!

Answer (score 0):

I accomplish this on my server in the following way:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

At a glance your configuration looks OK, but the [`return` directive documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) does note some limitations for older versions of nginx that would be encountered with your configuration.

Finally, in the secure server configuration, you could include an [*HTTP Strict Transport Security*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) directive to cause clients to only connect to your domain over TLS in the future.

```
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;
```

Comment: I've got the TLS portion in there.  What you posted is almost the same.  If I remove the `[::]:` portion in front of the port then I cover the first scenario I posted, but it still doesn't handle https://domain.com

Comment: Are you listing both `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` in the `servername` directive?

Comment: In the port 80 server, no.  I am in the port 443 server.  Should I be listing both in both server areas?  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post your current config to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Below config will redirect example.com to https://example.com

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    *.example.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
       listen         443 ssl;
       server_name    *.example.com;

       [....]
}
```

However, if you want to redirect all domains to https:

- change server_name to _ (server_name _;)
- replace $server_name variable to $host in redirect rule (return         301 https://$host$request_uri;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
server {
    listen          192.168.1.1:443 ssl;
    server_name     www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate www.example.com.crt;
    ...
}

server {
    listen          192.168.1.2:443 ssl;
    server_name     www.example.org;
    ssl_certificate www.example.org.crt;
    ...
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html